# Google Glass callbackUrl POST from Mirror API is empty?

Tags: python, google-mirror-api, google-glass, callbackurl

Apologies because the only web development I know is of the django/python kind and am probably guilty of mixing my  code idioms ( REST vs django URL dispatch workflow)

I have a URL handler which serves as a callbackUrl to a subscription for my Glassware. I am getting a POST to the handler , but the request object seems empty.

I am sure I am understanding this wrong but can someone point me in the direction of getting the "REPLY" information from a POST notification to a callbackURL.

My URL Handler is

`class A600Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):`

```
def post(self):
    """Process the value of A600 received and return a plot"""
    # I am seeing this in my logs proving that I am getting a POST when glass replies
    logging.info("Received POST to logA600")
    # This is returning None
    my_collection = self.request.get("collection")
    logging.info(my_collection)
    # I also tried this but self.sequest.POST is empty '[]' and of type UnicodeMultiDict
    # json_request_data = json.loads(self.request.POST)


@util.auth_required
def get(self):
    """Process the value of A600 received and return a plot"""
    logging.info("Received GET to this logA600")
```

I have the following URL Handler defined and can verify that the post function is getting a "ping" when the user hits reply by looking at the app-engine logs.

`MAIN_ROUTES = [
    ('/', MainHandler),('/logA600',A600Handler),
]`

How do I extract the payload in the form of the voice transcribed text sent by the user?. I am not understanding [The "parse_notification" example given in the docs](https://developers.google.com/glass/subscriptions?hl=en)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try [`request.body`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body)? The [docs for `request.POST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) state

> "If you need to access raw or non-form data posted in the request, access this through the HttpRequest.body attribute instead."

If the API isn't using form data in its post, you'll likely find the contents in `request.body`. [The docs to which you linked](https://developers.google.com/glass/subscriptions?hl=en) indicate that the content will be placed as JSON in the body instead of form data ("containing a `JSON` request body"). I would try `json.loads(request.body)`.

Comment: Thanks gotgenes , evrything was indeed stashed in the request body. As you pointed out from the way django handles it. request.POST.get("key") only works for form based POST information. The mirror API returns were all in self.request.body in my handler class above.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having this issue of Mirror API calling my application for notifications, and those notifications are empty.  My app runs on tomcat so its a java stack.  All the samples process the notification like this:

```
BufferedReader notificationReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
        String notificationString = "";

        // Count the lines as a very basic way to prevent Denial of Service
        // attacks
        int lines = 0;
        while (notificationReader.ready()) {
            notificationString += notificationReader.readLine();
            lines++;

            // No notification would ever be this long. Something is very wrong.
            if (lines > 1000) {
                throw new IOException(
                        "Attempted to parse notification payload that was unexpectedly long.");
            }
        }

        log.info("got raw notification " + notificationString);
```

For me this is always logging as empty.  Since a notification url must be https, and for testing I could not use an IP address, I have setup dyndns service to point to my localhost:8080 running service.  This all seems to work but I suspect how dyndns works is some type of forward or redirect here post data is removed.

How can I work around this for local development?

**Updated**:
Solved for me. 
I found closing the response before reading request caused issue that request.inputStream was already closed.  MOving this

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
Writer writer = response.getWriter();
writer.append("OK");
writer.close();
```

To after I fully read in request notification into a String solved the issue.

Comment: Note, if I use Google's proxy redirect service with my ip address hardcoded I also get called, but still empty request.  https://mirrornotifications.appspot.com/forward?url=http://1.2.3.4:8080/myapp-web/notify